# How do you call an as400 stored procedure with oledb?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, oledb, ibm-midrange, oledbconnection

I am trying to call a stored procedure from my code using oledb but I can't figure out how to do this. This is the code I wrote but it's not working

```
OleDbCommand sp = connectionDB.CreateCommand();
sp.CommandText = "CALL NASVARWG.§SP001('?','?','?','?','?','?')";
sp.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

sp.Parameters.Add("P1", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Char).Value = "ESANASTRIS";
sp.Parameters["P1"].Size = 10;
sp.Parameters["P1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

sp.Parameters.Add("P2", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Char).Value = "SAMNAS";
sp.Parameters["P2"].Size = 10;
sp.Parameters["P2"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

sp.Parameters.Add("P3", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Char).Value = "blah";
sp.Parameters["P3"].Size = 10;
sp.Parameters["P3"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

sp.Parameters.Add("P4", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Char);
sp.Parameters["P4"].Size = 2;
sp.Parameters["P4"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

sp.Parameters.Add("P5", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Char);
sp.Parameters["P5"].Size = 256;
sp.Parameters["P5"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

sp.Parameters.Add("P6", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Char).Value = textBox_Reparto.Text;
sp.Parameters["P6"].Size = 6;
sp.Parameters["P6"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

sp.Parameters.Add("P7", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Char).Value = "we can do this";
sp.Parameters["P7"].Size = 60;
sp.Parameters["P7"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

sp.Parameters.Add("P8", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Char).Value = "help";
sp.Parameters["P8"].Size = 256;
sp.Parameters["P8"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

sp.Prepare();
sp.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get an exception at "sp.Prepare();" telling me that the syntax of the command is wrong.

Comment: You are creating 8 parameters and your call has only 6 question marks. Maybe that's the reason?

Comment: @bdongus thanks for the Answer I noticed that and I have already corrected it but it still doesn't work it tells me NASVARWG it's not a valid Token, but I am sure this is the name of the mehod

Comment: Does your procedure really have the name NASVARWG.§SP001?

Comment: @bdongus yeas it does

Comment: @bdongus am I maybe missing a '{' ?!? if I can make it work in this way could you show me an other way to call a stored procedure from c#

Comment: Maybe NASVARWG/§SP001 works. Depending on your connection string  it could be you have to use the IBM i notation.

Comment: @bdongus I found out that this  out the call format it expected                        "{CALL NASVARWG.§SP001('?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?')}" in this way the NASVARWG.§SP001 is recognized but now I have a problem with he output parameters and this is the error I get SQL0469: IN, OUT o INOUT are no valid for parameter 3

Comment: How is your parameter 3 defined?

Comment: @bdongus I have been able to make it run without exception I removed the 3 output parameters from the stored procedures I have changed the CommandType.StoredProcedure to CommandType.Text now I don't get the exceptions but the stored Procedure doesn't run on the server as400, WHY ?!? why I don't get exception  but at the same time the procedure doesn't run??"

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use the IBM i Access ADO.NET drivers and place the program call in a stored procedure. They can convert the data from i to PC.

Answer (score 0):

As @Syafiqur__ mentioned the ADO.NET drivers are a better choice.

And as always there is an [IBM redbook](https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246440.html) about it. In my solutions I use the IBMDA400 version.

For your case it should look like this:

```cs
var command = new iDB2Command(cmdText: "§SP001", cmdType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, connection: masterSystemConnection);
var p1 = new iDB2Parameter(parameterName: "@P1", type: iDB2DbType.iDB2Char, size: 10);
    p1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    p1.Value = "ESANASTRIS";
    command.Parameters.Add(p1);
// ... all your other parameters, no call to Prepare
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Regarding your SQL0469:

Either change the attribute of the parameter on the DECLARE PROCEDURE, CREATE PROCEDURE, or ALTER PROCEDURE statement or change the parameter.

For additional details please have a look at the [IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzala/rzalaml.htm).

Bernd

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem  is most likely that you have **NO** parameter markers in your SQL statement.

```
sp.CommandText = "CALL NASVARWG.§SP001('?','?','?','?','?','?')";
```

The `'?'` are string constants, not parameter markers `?` which should appear without apostrophes. So the statement should really look like this:

```
sp.CommandText = "CALL NASVARWG.§SP001(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```